# Stack overflow exception before main()

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

this is my first question here on stackoverflow so I'll try to be specific. I searched the forums for any related topic but no luck. Anyway here goes:

I'm using Visual Studio 2005.I encountered a stack overflow exception :Unhandled exception at 0x775715de in IHR.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow. ,when attempting to debug my project. The call stack does not help as it stops at ntdll.dll, before even entering the main() function.

At first I suspected that it may be a compilation settings thing, but when I sent the executable compiled on my computer to a second computer, it could run fine, it just won't run on my machine.

The same happens in reverse, I compiled the executable on the second computer, it could run fine on that. But when I tried to run the executable that was compiled on the second computer on my computer, it couldn't run. All that appeared was a blank command prompt and a windows message saying the program was not responding.

I'm using Windows 7 Professional SP1, 64 bit. The other computer has the same OS version. Due to company policy, I can't post any source code here, but anyway I don't think it has anything to do with the source code. I suspect it may be a problem in the runtime environment. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Here's all there is on the call stack:

```
->ntdll.dll!775715de()  
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
ntdll.dll!775715de()    
ntdll.dll!7756014e()
```

Thanks to @WhozCraig's  suggestion, I have managed to get a more meaningful message on the call stack. Still stumped though.

> IHR.exe!_mbscmp(const unsigned char * s1=0x00fe8c10, const unsigned char * s2=0x00fe8c10)  Line 84 + 0xf bytes
>       IHR.exe!_mbscmp(const unsigned char * s1=0x00fe8c10, const unsigned char * s2=0x00fe8c10)  Line 84 + 0xf bytes
>       IHR.exe!strcmp(const char * _s1=0x00fe8c10, const char * _s2=0x00fe8c10)  Line 1646 + 0x2b bytes
>       IHR.exe!_mbscmp_l(const unsigned char * s1=0x00fe8c10, const unsigned char * s2=0x00fe8c10, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000)  Line 58 + 0xd bytes
>       IHR.exe!_mbscmp(const unsigned char * s1=0x00fe8c10, const unsigned char * s2=0x00fe8c10)  Line 84 + 0xf bytes
>       IHR.exe!strcmp(const char * _s1=0x00fe8c10, const char * _s2=0x00fe8c10)  Line 1646 + 0x2b bytes

here's some more, leading up to the stack above

```
IHR.exe!_mbscmp_l(const unsigned char * s1=0x00fe8c10, const unsigned char * s2=0x00fe8c10, localeinfo_struct * plocinfo=0x00000000)  Line 58 + 0xd bytes   C++
IHR.exe!_mbscmp(const unsigned char * s1=0x00fe8c10, const unsigned char * s2=0x00fe8c10)  Line 84 + 0xf bytes  C++
IHR.exe!strcmp(const char * _s1=0x00fe8c10, const char * _s2=0x00fe8c10)  Line 1646 + 0x2b bytes    
IHR.exe!_setlocale_get_all(threadlocaleinfostruct * ploci=0x002f13a0)  Line 1147 + 0x24 bytes   
IHR.exe!_setlocale_nolock(threadlocaleinfostruct * ploci=0x002f13a0, int _category=0, const char * _locale=0x00000000)  Line 966 + 0x9 bytes    C
```

> IHR.exe!setlocale(int _category=0, const char * _locale=0x00000000)  Line 826 + 0x1b bytes
>       IHR.exe!std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_ctor(std::_Locinfo * pLocinfo=0x0018f8f8, const char * locname=0x00ea591c)  Line 192 + 0x9 bytes
>       IHR.exe!std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo(const char * _Pch=0x00ea591c)  Line 78 + 0xd bytes
>       IHR.exe!std::ctype::ctype(const short * _Table=0x00000000, bool _Deletetable=false, unsigned int _Refs=0)  Line 1740 + 0x10 bytes
>       IHR.exe!std::ctype::_Getcat(const std::locale::facet * * _Ppf=0x0018fbd8)  Line 1760 + 0x4d bytes 
>       IHR.exe!std::use_facet >(const std::locale & _Loc={...})  Line 478 + 0x9 bytes 
>       IHR.exe!std::basic_ios >::widen(char _Byte=' ')  Line 124 + 0x34 bytes
>       IHR.exe!std::basic_ios >::init(std::basic_streambuf > * _Strbuf=0x00ff7908, bool _Isstd=false)  Line 135 + 0xa bytes
>       IHR.exe!std::basic_ostream >::basic_ostream >(std::basic_streambuf > * _Strbuf=0x00ff7908, bool _Isstd=false)  Line 53
>       IHR.exe!std::`dynamic initializer for 'cout''()  Line 13 + 0x16 bytes
>       IHR.exe!_initterm(void (void)* * pfbegin=0x00e8d10c, void (void)* * pfend=0x00e9dca0)  Line 855 
>       IHR.exe!_cinit(int initFloatingPrecision=1)  Line 293 + 0xf bytes
>       IHR.exe!**tmainCRTStartup()  Line 310 + 0x7 bytes
>
>       IHR.exe!mainCRTStartup()  Line 196
>
>       kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0x12 bytes
>
>       ntdll.dll!***RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes
>
>       ntdll.dll!*_RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes

It keeps repeatedly calling strcmp, mbscmp, mbscmp_l until it hits a stack overflow exception.

Update(11 April 2013): I've found the line that causes the problem, but am still totally clueless on why it's causing it. It's the usage of a strcmp.

```
struct Foo
{
    char text[4];
    bool operator < (const Foo &rhs) const
{
    return strcmp(text, rhs.text) < 0;
}
}
```

When this strcmp was commented out. The program did not crash. Any ideas or experience with dealing with such a problem? The same program still runs fine on other machines, but only crashes on my machine due to this line. other strcmp is used throughout the program with no issue. Thanks

Comment: Does a simple "hello world" program exhibit the same behavior? It not, it's something about your code, at least to some extent.

Comment: nope, Hello World doesn't cause this issue. If it's something to do with my code, why can it run on a different computer with the same OS ?

Comment: post stack trace, it might help

Comment: If it's happening before main(), it could be to do with static initialisation or maybe some mismatched runtime dependencies - have you got the same version of the VC runtime DLL's installed on both systems?

Comment: Try running the program as an administrator. Right click, "Run as administrator"

Comment: My bet is that you have too much static data or dynamic data allocated from constructors of static objects.

Comment: @roger_rowland Thanks for the information, could you elaborate more? How do I check for this? Thanks again

Comment: @VaibhavDesai. Thanks but I already tried that, still didn't work :)

Comment: @mikevil14rin - you could start by downloading the dependency walker to check each machine for the versions of dependent dll's but this won't help for side-by-side stuff - then you might look at sxstrace for help. You can also check Control Panel to see what VC runtimes (if any) have been specifically installed and check version numbers.

Comment: One other obvious check - you *have* done a virus scan on your machine haven't you?

Comment: Add Microsoft's symbol servers to your list of symbol sources (its a debug-configuration setting). There are plenty of [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy(v=vs.80).aspx) on the net that can tell you how to configure vs2005 to use them and download symbols for your specific OS and it's specific files. With these, every symbol in that stack dump will suddenly have meaning, and give you a much better picture of which part of the load is failing.

Comment: You can also try to change to size of the stack, but I don't think it will really solve your problem...

Comment: May be your ntdll.dll is corrupted. Have you tried replacing it?

Comment: Create a `hello world` project and add half the `cpp` files from your project. Build and run. If no problem, add half of the remaining files. If there is a problem remove half of the previously added files. Essentially, do a binary search for the `cpp` causing the problem. You should eventually find static variables defined in that compilation unit which are causing the startup problem.

Comment: Are you linking to any libraries. Maybe the library on the one system is corrupt or out of sync with the lib?

Comment: I meant add the other half of the files, not half of the remaining files. That would be almost like Zeno's paradox.

Comment: What's in the `text[4]` array? Is it a properly null-terminated c-string?

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that you have global/static variables and they are trying to initialize before you run main. Probably the order of actual initialization is not what you expect, as if you have them in different files, there is no way to tell in which order they should be created.

Either remove those variables or arrange them into the same file.